# Mongodb C# FindAsync. Filter on list inside document using linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongodb and I want to filter on a value inside a list in my documents.

My documents looks something like this:

```
{"_id": "guid" , "mylist": {"stuff": "a", "morestuff": "b"} }
```

I would like to find a document where "stuff" inside "mylist" is "a" by using linq expressions in FindAsync method.

My best effort so far:

```
collection.FindAsync(item => item.mylist.Where(item2 => item2.stuff == "a") )
```

Unfortunatly C# will not accept this statement and i am getting the following errors:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" to "bool"
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

I am relatively new to linq and have mostly been using resharper to do them for me, so I am probably missing something very basic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, i misanderstood your question, you just should replace `Where` (that gives you collection of items that pass to your expression) with `Any` that gives true back if there is any item in collection for that expression is true.

Use following query:

```
collection.FindAsync(Builders<YourClass>.Filter.ElemMatch(
                                     f=>f.mylist, item2=>item2.stuff=="a"))
```

I think, this one will work too:

```
collection.FindAsync(x=>x.mylist.Any(b=>b.stuff=="a"))
```

Comment: Ah great! Thank you!